Why was the ampere redefined in 2019?
Before 2019, the ampere was essentially defined by fixing the vacuum permeability $\mu_0$ to be $4\pi\times10^{-7} \frac{H}{m}$. From 2019 onwards, the ampere was essentially defined by fixing the elementary charge $e$ to be $1.602176634\times10^{-19} C$. Was there any motivation for this change? Both the vacuum permeability and the elementary charge are fundamental constants of the universe, so why did the International Bureau of Weights and Measures decide to switch the fundamental constant upon which the ampere was defined?

The standards bureau should only every consider redefinition of a unit if there is a precision improvement by the new definition; this is met with the new definition. Also, the $\mu_0$ is a relic of using SI units and should not have existed. It was a compromise made by genius pioneers who were confused about things. This is contrasted with the charge of proton, which is a real thing we can just straight up measure. i.e. The new definition has a perk of being conceptually cleaner.

Related: What are the proposed realizations in the New SI for the kilogram, ampere, kelvin and mole?

@naturallyInconsistent $\mu_0$ still exists and now it has to be measured. Whereas the electron charge no longer needs to be measured. Your reasoning would seem to favour the old system?

@ProfRob no, I'm very much in favour of the new system. However, the experiments that used to measure $e$ will now be reinterpreted as experiments that will now determine some unit scale else. Same thing with the $\mu_0$; the experiments that used to determine the unit scale because of inherent unnaturalness of SI units, will now instead be used to determine the numerical value of $\mu_0$ as is the newly necessary thing to do. Things are fine; the governing bodies are doing great jobs measuring everything properly. I'm looking forward to the next edition for the changes to percolate.

The vacuum permeability is still well-defined, albeit not exactly:
$$\mu_0=\frac{2\alpha h}{e^2c}.$$
The fine-structure constant is not known to perfect accuracy, but the accuracy is still very high.
In reality, it doesn't make any sense why permeability would be $4\pi\times10^{-7}$. The $4\pi$ part is fine, it shows up elsewhere too, but for it to be multiplied by exactly $10^{-7}$ is suspect since there's no reason why 0.00000001 should show up anywhere in nature.
Along with those changes, we also defined $c$, $h$, and a couple other constant to be exact. $c=299792458$ exactly, $h=6.62607015\times10^{-34}$ exactly, etc. This has actually been very convenient now that we don't need to add as many plus-or-minuses to calculations to account for inaccuracies. Keep in mind that we didn't change the constants, we changed the units we use to measure them so that they're exact. We didn't change what we consider to be the speed of light, we changed the meter to be exactly the distance that light covers in $1/299792458$ of a second (the second being defined as the time it takes for an isotope of cesium to oscillate a certain number of times).

Of course, the example with $c$ was fixed ages ago.

Is there any benefit to defining the ampere based on a fixed value of $e$ instead of $\mu_0$?

An amp has always been one coulomb per second. It's much simpler to define it in terms of the elementary charge now that it's exact, at the very least.
